# Sending messages to java server in objective-c via AsyncSocket

Tags: java, objective-c, sockets, stream, primitive

Hi I am trying to send messages to a Java server that I cannot change from an iOS device. I am using AsyncSocket and was wondering how to send and receive the length appended to the string. I am doing a UTF conversion of the string to NSData however I was wondering if there is a difference in the size of the primitive between the two languages. Also is there a big endian and little endian variation? Basically I need to be able to convert the following java methods:

```
inStream.readUTF();
inStream.readInt();
inStream.readChar();
inStream.readShort();
inStream.readFully(recvBuff, 0, recvLen);

outStream.writeInt();
outStream.writeUTF();
outStream.writeChars();
outStream.writeShort();
outStream.write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.length);
```

I know I am very close but something is not quite right, this is what I have got so far:

I am using an NSMutableArray to append the data and the using AsyncSockets read and write methods.

```
[theSocket readDataToData:[AsyncSocket ZeroData] withTimeout:timeout buffer:buffer bufferOffset:offset tag:tag]; // inStream.readUTF();
[theSocket readDataToLength:sizeof(int32_t) withTimeout:timeout buffer:buffer bufferOffset:offset tag:tag]; // inStream.readInt();
[theSocket readDataToLength:sizeof(unichar) withTimeout:timeout buffer:buffer bufferOffset:offset tag:tag]; // inStream.readChar();
[theSocket readDataToLength:sizeof(int16_t) withTimeout:timeout tag:tag]; // inStream.readShort();
[theSocket readDataWithTimeout:timeout buffer:buffer bufferOffset:offset maxLength:maxLength tag:tag]; // inStream.readFully(recvBuff, 0, recvLen);

[outputBufferStream appendBytes:&[sendString length] length:sizeof([sendString length])]; // outStream.writeInt();
[outputBufferStream appendData:[sendString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] // outStream.writeUTF();
char array[5];
[outputBufferStream appendBytes:array length:sizeof(array)]; // outStream.writeChars();
int16_t _short;
[outputBufferStream appendBytes:&_short length:sizeof(_short)]; // outStream.writeShort();
unsigned char *sendBytes;
[outputBufferStream appendBytes:sendBytes length:sendBytesLength]; // outStream.write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.length);
```

I usually append the length at the beginning like so:

```
int32_t sendStringLength = [sendString length];
[outputBufferStream appendBytes:&sendStringLength length:sizeof(sendStringLength)];
```

At the end of the write i am appending the following as a terminator:

```
[outputBufferStream appendData:[@"\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I would really appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

EDIT::

I have got most of it working thanks to Robadob. Here is a little java snippet (working) of the bit i am currently stuck trying to get working on Objective-C:

```
private int sendData(String stringToSend) {
    if (theSocket==null) {
        lastError="sendData() called before socket was set up.";
        return 1; // Error
    }

    try {
        System.out.println("Sending "+stringToSend.length()+" chars  ["+ stringToSend.length()*2+" bytes]");
        System.out.println("'" + stringToSend + "'");
        outStream.writeInt(stringToSend.length()*2);
        outStream.writeChars(stringToSend);
        outStream.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        lastError="sendData() exception: "+e;
        System.out.println(lastError);
        return 2; // Error
    }

    return 0; // Ok
}
```

Here is a snippet of what I have got so far in Objective-C:

```
- (int32_t)sendData:(NSString *)stringToSend {

    if (theSocket == nil) {
        lastError = @"sendData called before socket was set up";
        return 1; // Error
    }

    @try {

        NSLog(@"Sending %d chars  [%d bytes]", [stringToSend length], ([stringToSend length] * 2));
        NSLog(@"'%@'", stringToSend);

        uint32_t stringToSendInt = ([stringToSend length] * 2);
        uint32_t stringToSendIntBigE = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(stringToSendInt);
        [outputBufferStream appendBytes:&stringToSendIntBigE length:sizeof(stringToSendIntBigE)];
        stringToSend = [stringToSend stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
        for (int i = 0; i < ([stringToSend length]); i++) {
            unichar characterTmp = [stringToSend characterAtIndex:i];
            unichar character = characterTmp << 8;
            [outputBufferStream appendBytes:&character length:sizeof(character)];
        }

        [self syncWriteData:outputBufferStream withTimeout:socketTimeout tag:kSendDataSocketTag];
        outputBufferStream = [NSMutableData data];

    }
    @catch (NSException *e) {
        lastError = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sendData exception: %@", [e reason]];
        NSLog(@"%@", lastError);

        return 2; // Error
    }

    return 0; // Ok
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the docs for [writeUTF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29) it says it writes the first 2 bytes using [writeShort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeShort%28int%29). This says

> Writes a short to the underlying output stream as two bytes, high byte
>   first. If no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented
>   by 2.

A byte is 8 bits, so that makes the value they are writing is 16 bits, you are using `int32_t`, which is 32 bits. you should be writing an `int16` or `int16_t` (I don't objective-c).

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick reply i will correct this and see if it works :) and incase you were interested it is int16_t.

Comment: yeah i checked they are both 32 bits i have used int32_t just to be safe but i am not sure of the big endian/little endian conversion. thanks again for your help.

Comment: I managed to get it working partially I still can't seem to figure out how to convert the writeChars() method

Comment: So you are receiving the length correctly? if you read the docs for `writeChars(String)`, it just calls `writeChar()` for each character in the string in order.

Comment: not i am not getting  response on the length. the thing is when using write char how does java handle it? what is the encoding on the character? I have been looking at the java doc for writeChar() and trying different things but have not been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: I believe that internally the JVM represents strings as UTF-16, and the method docs for `writeChar()` say it dump the high byte and writesthe low, so this suggests if the char is represented as `00000000|11111111` only `11111111` is output. Your challenge would be to find out what the high 8 bytes usually tend to be and then stitch that back on before casting to UTF-16. Personally I'd probably stick with the `writeUTF8()` method for safety.

Comment: oh ok, thanks. the problem is i am trying to write some data to a server that for different types of calls uses different methods. Thanks to your advice I have managed to get the writeUTF working but in some instances I am required to use a combination of writeInt and writeChars: outStream.writeInt(stringToSend.length()*2); outStream.writeChars(stringToSend); so I am just trying to figure it out. If i get this sorted I should have everything working. Thanks again for all your help so far.

Comment: I would have thought you were able to write all strings via writeUTF8 and avoid the writeChar, writeChars and writeString methods. It would provide double the overhead as 2 bytes per character, but greatly simplify what your trying to achieve.

Comment: hmmm.... let me see if writeUTF works in this instance. If that is the case I can easily replace at writeChar()/writeChars() calls with writeUTF. I'll keep you posted

Comment: Nope when I writeUTF I am not getting a response from the server, will see if I can figure out the UTF-16 conversion. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was thinking you were able to modify the server and client. Try encoding your string as utf-16, then convert that to a byte[] and then only write the odd indexes of the array. I'm unsure how the writeChars() method specifies length of the string, the docs don't state that it does, so it might only support known length strings.

Comment: unfortunately no. I tried it, I think I've got a little closer, still not getting a response from the server but the converted data looks like it might be right. I feel like I'm missing something really small and obvious, lol. Yeah the server does expect a known length that is why I am appending the length of the bytes as a prefix before sending it. The method I have been using so far is to send the length in bytes and its working with the writeUTF method etc so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: Thanks anyways for all your help, I'll keep playing around with the code till I figure it out and I'll keep you posted.

Comment: You could throw together a quick Java application that uses the ByteOutputStream so you can see what you need to achieve. That would be better to reverse engineer it than to blindly brute force it as your currently doing.

Comment: I already have here is a little snippet of the working java code I am trying to convert:

Comment: I have updated question with the code since it is presented a lot better than it would in a comment.